# sending an email from different address

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I'm writing a program that has auto response in it. i.e. for example there is an user ad his email address would be `user@domain.com`, when ever someone writes an email to this address, there should be an auto response sent (Which I'm able to do it). but this should be sent from `autoReply@domain.com`(this is what I'm unable to know on how to do this). `autoReply@domain.com` is a shared mail box.

I'm using ews in my program and the below block of code is responsible to send the auto response.

```
private void replyToEmailWithURLs(ItemId itemId, List matchedKeyWords, String fromAddress) throws Exception {
        EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, itemId, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly));
        ResponseMessage responseMessage = message.createReply(false);

        message.getReplyTo().add(new EmailAddress("autoReply@domain.com"));
        // Add autoReply in CC
        responseMessage.getCcRecipients().add("autoReply@domain.com");
        String responseUrls = getTheResponseUrlsFromJsonFile(matchedKeyWords, fromAddress);
        responseMessage.setBodyPrefix(new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, responseUrls));
        responseMessage.sendAndSaveCopy();
        message.setIsRead(true);

    }
```

Here I tried to add a replyTo using `message.getReplyTo().add(new EmailAddress("autoReply@domain.com"));`, even this doesn't work.

I've seen a post here [set reply-to address in outgoing email EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988918/set-reply-to-address-in-outgoing-email-ews) , I was confused on the way it is working(basically given in c#), please let me know how can I get this done in Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with EWS, but apparently the standard JavaMail API supports [setting From or the sender address](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html).